# Empty String in python?

Tags: python, string, variables

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of the following code:

```
begin = None 
while begin != "": 
    begin = (raw_input("\nBegin:"))
```

What does `begin !=""` mean? What does the empty string `""` represent?

Comment: It tests whether the string has nothing in it.

Comment: variable begin not would be an empty string. Please read the docs, it's  a  basic question.

Comment: If the user just presses `Return` in response to the prompt, it will be set to the empty string.

Comment: Also note that that code is very unpythonic.  You would conventionally write `while not begin:` to test for the empty string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What does  begin !="" means?

It means `begin` does not refer to an empty string -- it's satisfied at the start (as `begin` refers to `None`, not to an empty string) and will stay satisfied as long as the user types anything else than just a `<return>`.

> What does the empty string  "" represent??

It represents what `raw_input` returns when the user just hits the `<return>` (AKA `<enter>`) key without actually typing anything at the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

`""` represents an empty string. So `begin != ""` is true whenever `begin` doesn't contain an empty string. The initial value `None` is not an empty string, so the loop will run at least once. After that, `begin` will contain whatever the user entered in response to the `Begin:` prompt. If he enters nothing (i.e. just presses <kbd>Return</kbd>) it will be an empty string, the test will fail, and the loop will end.